# FusedLocationProviderClient getCurrentLocation() fails

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to get a user's location with `FusedLocationProviderClient`.
This requires `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location`, but recent versions have changed `FusedLocationProviderClient` from a class to an interface.
This causes `fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation()` to fail with the error:

`java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but interface was expected`

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

I have tried using versions of `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location` before `FusedLocationProviderClient` was changed to an Interface, but they also fail with the error:

`JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallObjectMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getCurrentLocation(ILcom/google/android/gms/tasks/CancellationToken;)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient; or its super classes`